# ¿ Cómo corregir el problema de mi formulario?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, formularios

he creado un formulario de contacto en mi sitio web y añadi [un reCAPTCHA de Google](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/android.html) 
He seguido también los pasos del [sitio de descarga](http://reusableforms.com/d/b/php-contact-form-with-recaptcha).
He seguido los pasos que ahí se explican para configurar y al enviar el formulario, este se queda fijo en "enviando" ,sin llegar  a enviar.
Con el código que muestro, ¿ se podría detectar el error?, si bien solo modifique el archivo PHP que me indica.
Gracias.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/* Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )*/

require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['Name','Email'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('Email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('Message')->maxLength(6000);


$pp->requireReCaptcha();
$pp->getReCaptcha()->initSecretKey('Your ReCaptcha Secret Key Here');


$pp->sendEmailTo('miguelestabaenlaparra@gmail.com,  
miguel@webapplicationdeveloper.es'); // ← Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

```js
$(function()
{
    function after_form_submitted(data) 
    {
        if(data.result == 'success')
        {
            $('form#reused_form').hide();
            $('#success_message').show();
            $('#error_message').hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');

            jQuery.each(data.errors,function(key,val)
            {
                $('#error_message ul').append('<li>'+key+':'+val+'</li>');
            });
            $('#success_message').hide();
            $('#error_message').show();

            //reverse the response on the button
            $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function()
            {
                $btn = $(this);
                label = $btn.prop('orig_label');
                if(label)
                {
                    $btn.prop('type','submit' ); 
                    $btn.text(label);
                    $btn.prop('orig_label','');
                }
            });
            
        }//else
    }

 $('#reused_form').submit(function(e)
      {
        e.preventDefault();

        $form = $(this);
        //show some response on the button
        $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function()
        {
            $btn = $(this);
            $btn.prop('type','button' ); 
            $btn.prop('orig_label',$btn.text());
            $btn.text('Sending ...');
        });
        

                    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'handler.php',
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: after_form_submitted,
                dataType: 'json' 
            });        
        
      }); 
});
```

```css
@media  only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) 
{
    .form-container {
      padding: 5%;
      background: #ffffff;
      border: 9px solid #f2f2f2;            
      max-width: 520px;
      margin: auto;
    }

}

h1, p 
{
  text-align: center;
}

input, textarea , button
{
  width: 100%;
}    
textarea
{
  height: 200px;
}
button{
 background-color: #3bbec0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="form_container">
                    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

                    <h2>
                        Contacte conmigo
                    </h2>
                    <form method="post" id="reused_form">
                        <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
                        <input id="name" type="text" name="Name" required maxlength="50" placeholder="Nombre...">
                        <label for="email">Email :</label>
                        <input id="email" type="email" name="Email" required maxlength="50" placeholder="Correo electronico..." >
                        <label for="message">Mensage:</label>
                        <textarea id="message" name="Message" rows="10" maxlength="6000" required></textarea>
                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lf04UUUAAAAAOzCa7kflS9KY4mdMPJQAO8voaVP"></div>
                        <button class="button-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>
                    </form>
                    <div id="success_message" style="display:none">
                        <h3>Submitted the form successfully!</h3>
                        <p> We will get back to you soon. </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
                        <h3>Error</h3> Sorry there was an error sending your form. </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el apartado del archivo PHP : `$pp->requireReCaptcha();
$pp->getReCaptcha()->initSecretKey('Your ReCaptcha Secret Key Here');` debes poner la clave que te facilita google. **Your ReCaptcha Secret Key Here'**
Prueba y cuentas.